# Overlaying two plots using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are two data frames - `df1` & `df2` from which I need to create line plot using ggplot2 and display on the same graph.

## `df1`

```
 x   y 
2   30
4   25
6   20
8   15
```

## `df2`

```
 x   y 
2   12
4   16
6   20
8   24
```

for plotting the first df,

```
p1 <- ggplot( df1, aes(x = df1[,1] , y = log(df1[,2]) ) )
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(aes(y = log(df1[,2])))
p1
```

how do we get a same plot overlay on same graph for data frame `df2`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you redefine `data`, that will change where that geom layer is sourcing from. `ggplot` will always look to the initializing call for the aesthetic mappings and try to inherit from there, so you don't need to redfine `aes()` unless you want to change/add a mapping.

Also no need to use the `df[,2]` syntax, `ggplot` is already looking inside `df1` as soon as you set `data = df1`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = seq(2, 8, by = 2),
                  y = seq(30, 15, by = -5))
df2 <- data.frame(x = seq(2, 8, by = 2),
                  y = seq(12, 24, by = 4))

ggplot(df1, aes(x, log(y))) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_line(data = df2, color = "red") # re-define data and overwrite top layer inheritance
```

[image]

Comment: In the second geom_line(), can we use mapping=aes(...)? When I do that I'm getting this error for some reason:

"Error in `geom_point()`:
! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred."

Comment: you could do `+ geom_list(data = df2, aes(y = y2))` if `df2$y2` exists (it doesn't in this example data). Maybe the error you get is about the column not existing in your `data=`