# How to combine two ggplot2 objects into one plot (not figure)?

Tags: ggplot2

I've created two ggplot2 objects with histogram layers and stored them for later use. I'd like to merge them so that histogram from `plt1` is now semi-transparent and overlaid on top of `plt2`, both in one plot. How can I:

1. add `alpha` to a histogram after it is created?
2. merge the plots together?

They are based on different data. Note: I know how to plot two datasets in one plot. I want to merge plots that are already created, somehow restore data from them). MRE:

```
library(tidyverse)

data1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(300, 0, 1))
data2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(300, 1, 3))
plt1 = ggplot(data1, aes(x = x, y = ..density..)) + geom_histogram()
plt2 = ggplot(data2, aes(x = x, y = ..density..)) + geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to a similar question that may help

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = seq(2, 8, by = 2),
              y = seq(30, 15, by = -5))
[df2 <- data.frame(x = seq(2, 8, by = 2),
                  y = seq(12, 24, by = 4))][1]

ggplot(df1, aes(x, log(y))) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_line(data = df2, color = "red") # re-define data and overwrite top layer inheritance
```

[Overlaying two plots using ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297206/overlaying-two-plots-using-ggplot2-in-r)

Also here is the answer to your question on setting alpha

```
#example of using alpha to fade scatter point markers    
p + geom_point(alpha = 1/10)
```

[ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html#alpha)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bind_rows` to bind and name (using `.id`) the two datasets, then plot them together with some `alpha`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

data1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(300, 0, 1))
data2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(300, 1, 3))

both_df <- bind_rows(data1 = data1, data2 = data2, .id = "dataset")

ggplot(both_df, aes(x, ..density.., fill = dataset)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.6, position = "identity")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>